# Only one comment displayed in recyclerview - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app the registered user can successfully post comments. Now in my code, I do a check. If the specific news title has a comment then populate the recycled view. If not then display a text view saying hey there are no comments posted. However, only one comment is shown instead of the totals.

This is the check I was talking about.

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("comments").orderByChild("newsTitle").equalTo(newsTitle);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Comment comment = dataSnapshots.getValue(Comment.class);

                    //mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

                    commentArrayList.add(comment);

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(displayCommentsAdapter);

                    displayCommentsAdapter = new DisplayCommentsAdapter(getApplication(),commentArrayList);

                    displayCommentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //displayCommentsAdapter.setCommentsData(commentArrayList);

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "commentArrayList size: " + String.valueOf(commentArrayList.size()));

                }
                //commentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                //Toast.makeText(DisplayComments.this,"There are no comments posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                noCommentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The

```
 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "commentArrayList size: " + 
 String.valueOf(commentArrayList.size()));
```

successfully returns the size of the array list. ie. 10 comments the ArrayList size is 10. So that part is good.

The logcat is giving me another message too.

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Maybe this has to do something with my current problem.

The DisplayComments activity is found [here](https://github.com/theo82/Capstone-Udacity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/theo/tziomakas/news/DisplayComments.java).

And my adapter code [here](https://github.com/theo82/Capstone-Udacity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/theo/tziomakas/news/adapters/DisplayCommentsAdapter.java).

The single_comment_row.xml is [here](https://github.com/theo82/Capstone-Udacity/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/single_comment_row.xml)

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your adapter outside the loop

```
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Comment comment = dataSnapshots.getValue(Comment.class);

                //mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

                commentArrayList.add(comment);



                //displayCommentsAdapter.setCommentsData(commentArrayList);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "commentArrayList size: " + String.valueOf(commentArrayList.size()));

            }

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(displayCommentsAdapter);

            displayCommentsAdapter = new DisplayCommentsAdapter(getApplication(),commentArrayList);

            displayCommentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //commentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else{
            //Toast.makeText(DisplayComments.this,"There are no comments posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            noCommentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
```

**EDIT**

Change the hight of your `ConstraintLayout` to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`**

Comment: @Theo change the hight of your `ConstraintLayout` to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`**